# How to revise Google Script to extract multiple fields form JSON (API)

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, flatmap

I'm using this script to extract specific fields from multiple arrays:

```
var values = json.data.flatMap(({ productId, cannabinoidInformation, weightTierInformation }) => cannabinoidInformation.map(({ lowerRange, name }, i) => [productId, lowerRange, name, weightTierInformation[i].name, weightTierInformation[i].gramAmount]));
```

For this API: https://flowhub.stoplight.io/docs/public-developer-portal/a377fa23cdec5-inventory-items-by-location

I'm revised the script to:

```
var values = json.orders.flatMap(({ name, payments,itemsInCart }) => payments.map(({ amount,
paymentType }, i) => [name,amount,
paymentType,itemsInCart[i].quantity, itemsInCart[i].sku]));
```

I'm trying to make it work with the following API: https://flowhub.stoplight.io/docs/public-developer-portal/b41c3d4f8d234-orders-by-location

But I'm getting this error: Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity')

How can I revise the script above to fix the error message I'm getting?

Unfortunately, the mock server doesn't work for the API above and I can't share the keys due to privacy reasons

Here is an example of the response:

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "clientId": "string",
      "createdAt": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
      "completedOn": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
      "customerId": "string",
      "currentPoints": 0,
      "Name": "string",
      "orderStatus": "Pending",
      "orderType": "in-store",
      "orderId": "string",
      "totals": {
        "FinalTotal": 0,
        "SubTotal": 0,
        "TotalDiscounts": 0,
        "TotalFees": 0,
        "TotalTaxes": 0
      },
      "itemsInCart": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "sku": "string",
          "category": "BulkBud",
          "title1": "string",
          "title2": "string",
          "productName": "string",
          "strainName": "string",
          "unitOfWeight": "Each",
          "quantity": 0,
          "unitPrice": 0,
          "totalPrice": 0,
          "unitCost": 0,
          "totalCost": 0,
          "itemDiscounts": [
            {
              "_id": "string",
              "name": "string",
              "type": "string",
              "discountAmount": 0,
              "discountType": "string",
              "discountId": "string",
              "dollarsOff": 0,
              "penniesOff": 0,
              "percentOff": 0,
              "discounterName": "string",
              "discounterId": "string",
              "isCartDiscount": true,
              "couponCode": "string",
              "quantity": 0
            }
          ],
          "tax": [
            {
              "_id": "string",
              "name": "string",
              "percentage": 0,
              "calculateBeforeDiscounts": "string",
              "supplierSpecificTax": true,
              "excludeCustomerGroups": [
                "string"
              ],
              "enableCostMarkup": true,
              "markupPercentage": 0,
              "thisTaxInPennies": 0,
              "appliesTo": "all"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "customerType": "recCustomer",
      "locationId": "string",
      "voided": true,
      "fullName": "string",
      "budtender": "string",
      "payments": [
        {
          "_id": "string",
          "paymentType": "cash",
          "amount": 0,
          "cardId": "string",
          "loyaltyPoints": 0,
          "debitProvider": "string",
          "balanceAfterPayment": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the following fields:

1. name
2. payments > payments
3. payments > paymentType
4. itemsInCart >quantity
5. itemsInCart >sku

Comment: I think that in this case, it is required to know the data. So, can you provide the sample data. In the case of your script, can you provide the sample data of `JSON.stringify(json)`?

Comment: There is a response example from the API, would you like me to share live data @Tanaike? https://flowhub.stoplight.io/docs/public-developer-portal/b41c3d4f8d234-orders-by-location

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question and your expected result. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In this case, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Your English is great! I just didn't explain it correctly, I added the response example to the questions (I can't add it as a comment because it's too big) 
Thank you so much @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample value, `payments > payments` is `payments > amount`? If it's so, I think that your showing 2nd script works. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251262/discussion-between-kal-el-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is map `payments` and `itemsInCart` into smaller arrays with the info you need. Extracting `name` is straightforward. Try the snippent below and let me know if it works for you, of if you need me to change something.

```js
const apiResult = {
  total: 0,
  orders: [
    {
      id: 'string',
      clientId: 'string',
      createdAt: '2019-08-24T14:15:22Z',
      completedOn: '2019-08-24T14:15:22Z',
      customerId: 'string',
      currentPoints: 0,
      Name: 'string',
      orderStatus: 'Pending',
      orderType: 'in-store',
      orderId: 'string',
      totals: {
        FinalTotal: 0,
        SubTotal: 0,
        TotalDiscounts: 0,
        TotalFees: 0,
        TotalTaxes: 0,
      },
      itemsInCart: [
        {
          id: 'string',
          sku: 'string',
          category: 'BulkBud',
          title1: 'string',
          title2: 'string',
          productName: 'string',
          strainName: 'string',
          unitOfWeight: 'Each',
          quantity: 0,
          unitPrice: 0,
          totalPrice: 0,
          unitCost: 0,
          totalCost: 0,
          itemDiscounts: [
            {
              _id: 'string',
              name: 'string',
              type: 'string',
              discountAmount: 0,
              discountType: 'string',
              discountId: 'string',
              dollarsOff: 0,
              penniesOff: 0,
              percentOff: 0,
              discounterName: 'string',
              discounterId: 'string',
              isCartDiscount: true,
              couponCode: 'string',
              quantity: 0,
            },
          ],
          tax: [
            {
              _id: 'string',
              name: 'string',
              percentage: 0,
              calculateBeforeDiscounts: 'string',
              supplierSpecificTax: true,
              excludeCustomerGroups: ['string'],
              enableCostMarkup: true,
              markupPercentage: 0,
              thisTaxInPennies: 0,
              appliesTo: 'all',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      customerType: 'recCustomer',
      locationId: 'string',
      voided: true,
      fullName: 'string',
      budtender: 'string',
      payments: [
        {
          _id: 'string',
          paymentType: 'cash',
          amount: 0,
          cardId: 'string',
          loyaltyPoints: 0,
          debitProvider: 'string',
          balanceAfterPayment: 0,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

(function () {
  const {orders}= apiResult;
  const result = orders.reduce((acc, order) => {
    const {Name: name, payments: _payments, itemsInCart: _itemsInCart } = order;
    const payments = _payments.map(payment => ({amount: payment.amount, type: payment.paymentType}))
    const itemsInCart = _itemsInCart.map(item => ({ quantity: item.quantity, sku: item.sku }))
    return [...acc, { name, payments, itemsInCart }]
  }, []);
  console.log(result)
})();
```

Comment: Great idea @Dmitry Kostyuk will you be able to revise the code that you created to fit one var that I can insert into my script? 

`targetsheet.getRange(2, 1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);`

Comment: Well, you won't be able to use `setValues()` directly here, because you have one `name` but multiple `payments` and `itemsInCart`. You would need to normalize those. Share a screenshot of what you want the result to look like and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Tanaike was able to use the `setvalues()` on a different API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180135/how-to-revise-google-script-app-to-extract-multiple-arrays-and-combine-them-into#

is there any way to implement it here in a more simple way so I can revise it to add arrays and non-array items? @Dmitry Kostyuk

Comment: He used `flatmap`, which is the same as using `flat` then `map`. Not directly applicable to the problem I described. Until I know what you need, I won't be able to help further :)

Comment: Sorry about that, to make it simple, in my questions I have an example of the response, I want to extract all the items (including all the items within arrays) into GS (each item into a separate column) 
for example:

- the first item in the example is "_id", I want it to be added to the A column 

- the 2nd item is "clientId", I want it to be added to the B column, etc

I want all the items to go into a "values" var: `targetsheet.getRange(2, 1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);` @Dmitry Kostyuk