# How to revise Google Script App to extract multiple arrays and combine them into one var

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, flatmap

For this API: https://flowhub.stoplight.io/docs/public-developer-portal/a377fa23cdec5-inventory-items-by-location
I'm using this script to extract specific fields from multiple arrays:

```
function test(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");

var options = {
     //"async": true,
     //"crossDomain": true,
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "clientId" : "1",
       "key": "1",
       "Prefer": "code=200",
       "Prefer":"dynamic=true"
       
       }}




  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/locations/1/inventory",options).getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);


var values = json.data.flatMap(({ productId, cannabinoidInformation, weightTierInformation }) => cannabinoidInformation.map(({lowerRange,name }, i) => [productId, lowerRange, name, weightTierInformation[i].name, weightTierInformation[i].gramAmount]));



targetsheet.getRange(2, 1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

}
```

At the moment the script generates the following output:

- Column A: productId
- Column B: cannabinoidInformation > lowerRange
- Column C: cannabinoidInformation > name
- Column D:weightTierInformation > name
- Column E: weightTierInformation > gramAmount

I want to revise this code from 1 var:

```
var values = json.data.flatMap(({ productId, cannabinoidInformation, weightTierInformation }) => cannabinoidInformation.map(({lowerRange,name }, i) => [productId, lowerRange, name, weightTierInformation[i].name, weightTierInformation[i].gramAmount]));
```

Into 3 var:

1. `var ci = json.data.flatMap(({cannabinoidInformation }) => cannabinoidInformation.map(({lowerRange,name }) => [lowerRange, name]));`
2. `var wi = json.data.flatMap(({weightTierInformation }) => weightTierInformation.map(({name,gramAmount }) => [name, gramAmount]));`

**3. `var values` - I would like to insert here all the arrays to something like this:productId,ci and wi**

That way I can have one final var ("values") which will output all the fields in the order I enter them (I would like to keep the same order A-E as it's outputting now)

Comment: Can you please help to revise the code? @Tanaike

Comment: I think that your showing script achieves your goal. But, in your goal, you are required to split it with `var ci =` and `var wi =` and `var values`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in this case, you are not required to retrieve `productId`. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: What I would like is: var values= productId(A), ci (B-C), wi (D-E)
Please let me know if I'm not clear enough, I will try to explain in a different way @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I think that you might have misunderstood my comment. I think that your showing script has already achieved your goal. So, I cannot understand your expected goal in this question. So, I asked about the detail of your goal.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't explain it correctly, your English is GREAT!

What I have now: 1 var that maps multiple arrays and non-array items
What I want: 1 var per array - so in the example above there is one item and 2 arrays (each one has 2 times) so a total of 5 items

I want to break down each array into a var and combine all the vars (2) into 1 main var

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, can you confirm my 1st comment, again? Because, from your reply, I would like to ask the same question with my 1st comment. If you cannot understand it, please tell me. I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yes, I want to split the code that you created into 2 vars but I still need to be able to add to var values items as productId, so for your questions I still need the "productId" 
I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough I can make a demo @Tanaike

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, from your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike will that be OK if I will create new questions to make more modifications?

Comment: When I saw your new question and I could correctly understand it, I would like to try to think of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your reply, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = json.data.flatMap(({ productId, cannabinoidInformation, weightTierInformation }) => cannabinoidInformation.map(({lowerRange,name }, i) => [productId, lowerRange, name, weightTierInformation[i].name, weightTierInformation[i].gramAmount]));
```

#### To:

```
var ci = json.data.flatMap(({ cannabinoidInformation }) => cannabinoidInformation.map(({ lowerRange, name }) => [lowerRange, name]));
var wi = json.data.flatMap(({ weightTierInformation }) => weightTierInformation.map(({ name, gramAmount }) => [name, gramAmount]));
var productIds = json.data.flatMap(({ productId, weightTierInformation }) => Array(weightTierInformation.length).fill(productId));
var values = productIds.map((e, i) => [e, ...ci[i], ...wi[i]]);
```

- In this modification, in order to retrieve `productId`, `productIds` is added. And, the values of `ci`, `wi`, `productIds` are merged.

Comment: You did it again! amazing!! you are the best!!! @Tanaike